# Dynamic argument parser for python

Tags: python, argparse

I am building a small wrapper which can accept a python command infer args and their associated values on the fly. I want something like and arg parser but the catch is that I do not know the arguments in advance. For example, I can get as input:

```
python some_script.py --arg1 val1 --arg2 val2 --arg3 val3
```

I want some dictionary `{arg1: val1, arg2: val2, arg3: val3}`

Comment: You mean like `sys.argv`…?

Comment: You need to be clear as to what features of `argparse` you want.  Otherwise, just looking at `sys.argv` directly will do.  In fact for a basic program it's a good idea to practice working directly from it.  Then you can appreciate what parsers like `argparse` provide.

Comment: `sys.argv` would work from within the executed script? I was looking for passing in a cmd string and being able to extract out arguments and passed values for the args.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so like this:

```
import argparse
import sys

# Create an ArgumentParser object
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

# Add arguments to the parser dynamically based on the command-line arguments
for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
    if arg.startswith('--'):
        # Get the argument name and add it to the parser
        arg_name = arg[2:]
        parser.add_argument(arg, dest=arg_name)

# Parse the command-line arguments
args = parser.parse_args()

# Access the values of the arguments as a dictionary
arg_dict = args.__dict__

print(args_dict)

>> {'test': '0', 'test2': '1'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import argparse
import sys

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
    if arg.startswith("--"):
        parser.add_argument(arg)

options, not_parsed = parser.parse_known_args()
options = vars(options)

print(f"{options=}")
print(f"{not_parsed=}")
```

Sample runs:

```
$ python3 main.py --arg1 val1 --arg2 val2 --arg3 val3 --foo foovalue one two three --blah blah
options={'arg1': 'val1', 'arg2': 'val2', 'arg3': 'val3', 'foo': 'foovalue', 'blah': 'blah'}
not_parsed=['one', 'two', 'three']

$ python3 main.py --arg1 val1 --arg2 val2 --arg3 val3 --foo foovalue one two three --bar wine 
options={'arg1': 'val1', 'arg2': 'val2', 'arg3': 'val3', 'foo': 'foovalue', 'bar': 'wine'}
not_parsed=['one', 'two', 'three']

$ python3 main.py --arg1 val1 --arg2 val2 --arg3 val3 --foo moo one two three --bar wine
options={'arg1': 'val1', 'arg2': 'val2', 'arg3': 'val3', 'foo': 'moo', 'bar': 'wine'}
not_parsed=['one', 'two', 'three']
```